# How to run Drupal console command from code?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, symfony-console

I have found a lot of documentation on how to run Drush commands from code, but I'm specifically looking on how to run a [Drupal Console](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/index.html) command from code.

I have some experience in Symfony and I know how to run a Symfony command from code. Since a Drupal console command extends on Symfony command, I thought this should be rather easy. Simply following [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html) doesn't amount to anything though.

I am trying to run a command in a `hook_cron()` implementation in a custom module.

Comment: Just found the Drupal stackexchange, so I asked the question there too. Can't close this since the Drupal stackexchange isn't listed at the "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "ve asked this question at the Drupal SE and got a fine answer there: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239501/how-to-run-drupal-console-command-from-code